# issue in initializing fragment from the activity in xamarin android?

Tags: android, xamarin, fragment

This is my Activity class:

```
 private void pushFragment(Fragment fragment)
    {
        if (fragment == null)
            return;

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = SupportFragmentManager;

        if (fragmentManager != null)
        {
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            if (ft != null)
            {
                ft.AddToBackStack("");
                ft.Replace(Resource.Id.rootLayout, fragment);
                ft.Commit();
            }
        }
    }

public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        if (FragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount > 0)
        {
            FragmentManager.PopBackStack();
            //Finish();
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

When I click on the close icon of the layout it will call `pushFragment(new ParentFragment());`
[image]

The close button on top of the right, when clicked must go to fragment but it's not working?

Comment: Your code seems no problem, have you debug your project, when you click the close button, it did execute the `pushFragment` method ?

Comment: Yes, it execute and calls the fragment but when the call comes back to the calling method from there it goes into the break mode and it does not show any specific error. I'm using Visual Studio 2017. @YorkShen-MSTF

Comment: You can see more information in [diagnostic build output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output) mode.

Comment: Not getting any proper error message with this solution. @YorkShen-MSFT

Comment: Have  you add a try/catch to catch the exception ? Troubleshooting this issue will be much easier if you include information from the crash.

Comment: Yes i have used try catch, still any help regards use of try catch to get error message in xamarin??? The above solution of using diagnostic build output gives this message: 11-27 11:16:15.541 D/AndroidRuntime( 4298): Shutting down VM
11-27 11:16:15.543 D/Mono    ( 4298): [0xb033f300] worker unparking, timeout? no interrupted? no
11-27 11:16:15.543 D/Mono    ( 4298): [0xb033f300] worker parking
11-27 11:16:15.543 D/Mono    ( 4298): [0xb0518300] worker unparking, timeout? no interrupted? no @YorkShen-MSFT

Comment: You mean when you execute `pushFragment(new ParentFragment())` method, your project just directly goes into the break mode and there is no any other error message ?

Comment: Yes, that is what i'm try to overcome! @YorkShen-MSFT

Comment: That's wierd, would you mind share a basic demo  to reproduce this problem ?

Comment: where i can send you that demo code?? @YorkShen-MSFT

Comment: You could share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem through online repo, such as Github. And please don't contain any personal information in your project.

Comment: The issue is like that, I have called Activity1 from main activity, from Activity1 i have called fragment1 which have one button on click of that button i have called Activity2 that activity2 have button named "go back to fragment" when i click on this button it must have to go to fragment1, but is xamarin android it goes into break mode and not give any specific error.